# Для Элемент модели, переданный в словарь, имеет тип "...", но для этого словаря требуется элемент модели типа "System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[...]

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

Элемент модели, переданный в словарь, имеет тип "WebApplication3.Models.GuestResponse", но для этого словаря требуется элемент модели типа "System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[WebApplication3.Models.GuestResponse]".

```html
@using WebApplication3.Models
@model IList<GuestResponse>

@{
 Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <table class="table">
  @if (Model != null)
  {
   for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
   {
    <tr><td>@Model[i].Name</td><td>@Model[i].Email</td><td>@Model[i].Phone</td><td><img src="~/Files/@Model[i].Photo" /></td></tr>
   }
  }
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

В чём здесь может быть проблема?

Comment: В том, что Вы передаете в представление объект `GuestResponse`, а нужно `IList<GuestResponse>`. Как Вы вызываете в контроллере метод `View`?

Comment: Благодарю, осознал, передавал только один экземпляр класса, а не список, теперь всё всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась, код контроллера теперь выглядит как-то так, в представлении ничего не менял

```
List<GuestResponse> Students;


    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        ViewBag.Greeting = hour < 12 ? "Доброе утро" : "Доброго дня";
        Students = new List<GuestResponse> {
            new GuestResponse {Name = "ahrtfhar", Email = "agrrarh", Phone = "agrrarh", Photo = "Stoned_Fox_.jpg" },
            new GuestResponse {Name = "strjtrr", Email = "ajtaj", Phone = "gluifat", Photo = "Stoned_Fox_.jpg" }
    };
        return View(Students);


    }
```